# How best to trigger event on file drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

Simple enough question, but I've spent a few hours and can't figure it out.

Some background:

1. Using dropzone.js I have set an entire page to be a dropzone.
2. I properly handle the file upload.

Issue:

I want to trigger a JavaScript function to do something (lets say trigger an alert) whenever a person drops any file anywhere on the screen.  How would I best achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropzone.js has a `drop` event which can be triggered like below:

```
$(function() {
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
  myDropzone.on("drop", function(file) {
    //code here
   });
})
```

see http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events for all events.

Comment: So this only will trigger on the dropzone listed in the 2nd line?  How can i make it work on any dropzone?

Comment: You have to specify every dropzones drop function, but what you can do is make a generic callback function and call that on the drop function. But make sure when creating multiple dropzones on 1 page to disable `autoDiscover`